# Работа с wav файлом: конвертация 16-битного файла в 8-битный

Tags: c++, аудио

Помогите с реализацией на c++. Собственно необходимо переписать wav файл с 16 на 8 бит. Прочитал спек wav файла, успешно его смог открыть и прочитать о нем данные, перезаписать в новый файл. А вот как именно работать с изменением глубины звучания - битности?

Вот как я переписываю из одного файла в другой:

```
output = fopen("Output.wav", "w+b");
fwrite(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, output);
for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++) // запись семплов во второй файл
{
    // short* adr = &abc;
    fread(&header, header.bitsPerSample / 8,1,file);
    fwrite(&header,header.bitsPerSample / 8,1,output);

}
fclose(output);
```

Comment: А при чём тут C++?

Comment: @klopp понятия не имею на самом деле, возможно реализация поставленной задачи происходит на с++

Comment: Зачем вам понадобилось экономить на битах? Это буквально прошлый век. Качество будет ужасным. Не надо так делать.

Comment: @Athari учебный процесс требует делать все то что сделано самому, и изобретать свой велосипед.

Comment: здесь как раз самый что ни на есть стандартный C++. Используется библиотека fstream для работы с файлами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вас не волнует качество — делите 16-битные значения на 256 и получайте 8-битные. Ну и в заголовке поменяйте информацию соответственно. Вот, собствено, и всё.

Учтите, что уровень шума будет очень высоким, и вам совершенно не понравится звучание.

Comment: собственно если смотреть на спек к wav формату там 16 битные значения это:
'unsigned short audioFormat;
unsigned short numChannels;
unsigned short blockAlign;
unsigned short bitsPerSample;'

из всего этого первое это аудиоформат, второе колво каналов, третье байт для одного семпла, и последнее глубина

Comment: @KappaPolice Формат, каналы и выравнивание (чего?) останутся прежними, вам надо будет обновить bitsPerSample, я так понимаю. Если сомневаетесь, какие должны быть значения, просто создайте в любом редакторе файл нужного вида и подсмотрите значения.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь, все сработало. Оказалось что проблема очень даже проста, но решение пришло не сразу из-за усталости и не хотелось прострелить себе колено как всегда в c++

Comment: *"не хотелось прострелить себе колено как всегда в c++"* у вас таки нет ни строчки на C++ :-) Вы этот язык с C не путаете? Вот как раз там ногу прострелить проще всего. На плюсах куда сложней. Или, если уж цитировать классику:  *C++: Вы случайно создаете дюжину копий объекта «вы» и всем им простреливаете ногу. Срочная медицинская помощь оказывается невозможной, так как вы не можете разобраться, где настоящие копии, а где — те, что только указывают на них и говорят: «А вот он я!»*